# How does the less dense air affect the reciprocating aircraft engine performance?

Tags: density-altitude

How does the less dense air can affect the reciprocating engine performance ? For an example " rotax engine "

Answer (score 1):

Lower air density means less compression, hence less mean effective cylinder pressure during expansion, and thus less power, since shaft power is proportional to the product of mean effective pressure and angular speed...

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help